# How to fade image when hovering link or element?

Tags: css, opacity

#### My code :

```css
.element {
    position:fixed;
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:10px;
    background:#ffffff;
    height:50px;
    width:500px;
}
    
.element:hover {
    background:#000;
}

.element img {
    float:left;
    height:30px;
    width:30px;
    opacity:1;
}
    
.text {
    display:inline-block;
    height:37px;
    width:183px;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet">
    <div class="element">
        <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/6d8ebb117e8d83d74ea95fbdd0f87e13?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG">
        <div class="text">Jon Skeet</div>
    </div>
</a>
```

---

#### My problem :

I'm trying to add opacity to the image when hovering the .element/link. I already managed to change the background, but I can't seem to find out a way to make the image fade.

I already tried `.element:hover .element img {opacity:.7}` but it didn't work...

Thank you!

Comment: you need just `.element:hover img{opacity:.7}`

Comment: And you don't need jQuery....

Comment: thank you two very much, i already deleted the jquery tag. ^^

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this code :

```
.element:hover img { opacity:.7;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `.element img:hover {opacity: 0.5;}`

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS you tried is wrong, use this:

```
.element:hover img {opacity:.7}
```

Comment: Way to take someone's comment and turn it into an answer *without* attributing the solution to the commenter....

Comment: the easiest, shortest, cleanest solution is just one... I wouldn't say that he took someone's else solution without properly attribution. And looking at the timestamp the first commenter and Matthew posted quite in the same moment

Comment: To cale_b - if you had looked, you would have seen theres probably like 20 seconds between our 2 answers - I had no idea there was another answer!